# SQL Server Stored Procedure Error while trying to create an insert procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I am created a stored procedure in SQL Server and I'm getting this error but, I'm not sure what it means.

The following is the procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Grant_Append]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (@GrantNumber AS VARCHAR(50), 
     @GrantName AS VARCHAR(100),
     @ProjectCode AS VARCHAR(50),
     @LOCID AS INT,
     @Comments AS VARCHAR(100),
     @Provider AS VARCHAR(100),
     @ISAT AS NCHAR(10),
     @TypeID AS INT,
     @Slots AS FLOAT,
     @Patients AS FLOAT,
     @FundingMethod AS VARCHAR(50),
     @L1600 AS MONEY,
     @L1602 AS MONEY,
     @L1603 AS MONEY,
     @L1608 AS MONEY,
     @L1612 AS MONEY,
     @ADAAFunding AS MONEY,
     @ProgramBudget AS MONEY,
     @Jurisdiction AS INT,
     @VersionType AS VARCHAR(20),
     @VersionNum AS INT)
AS BEGIN
 INSERT INTO dbo.Grant
    (GrantNumber,
     GrantName,
     ProjectCode,
     LOCID,
     Comments,
     Provider,
     ISAT,
     TypeID,
     Slots,
     Patients,
     FundingMethod,
     [1600],
     [1602],
     [1603],
     [1608],
     [1612],
     ADAAFunding,
     ProgramBudget,
     Jurisdiction,
     VersionType,
     VersionNum, 
     SubmitDate)
      -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT @GrantNumber, 
            @GrantName,
            @ProjectCode,
            @LOCID,
            @Comments,
            @Provider,
            @ISAT,
            @TypeID,
            @Slots,
            @Patients,
            @FundingMethod,
            @1600,
            @1602,
            @1603,
            @1608,
            @1612,
            @ADAAFunding,
            @ProgramBudget,
            @Jurisdiction,
            @VersionType,
            @VersionNum,
            getdate()
END
```

These are the errors:

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Grant_Append, Line 30
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Grant'.
>
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure Grant_Append, Line 65
>
>   Must declare the variable '@1600'*

Comment: And for your second error you declare `@L1600` but then try to use `@1600`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GRANT` is a Reserved keyword. It should be delimited to avoid error, eg

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[Grant] ....
```

- [SQL Server Delimited Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [SQL Server Reserved Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

there are also typos in your parameters,

```
        @1600,
        @1602,
        @1603,
        @1608,
        @1612,
```

when it should be

```
        @L1600,
        @L1602,
        @L1603,
        @L1608,
        @L1612,
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend changing your table name from [Grant], which is a reserved keyword, to something not reserved, i.e. [Grants]. Also, I'd suggest not beginning column names with numbers. So, for instance, prefix [1600] with something descriptive. I've used "fee" as an example. Here's a working code sample for you:

```
-- DROP TABLE dbo.Grants
CREATE TABLE dbo.Grants
(
GrantNumber VARCHAR(50), 
GrantName VARCHAR(100),
ProjectCode VARCHAR(50),
LOCID INT,
Comments VARCHAR(100),
Provider VARCHAR(100),
ISAT NCHAR(10),
TypeID INT,
Slots FLOAT,
Patients FLOAT,
FundingMethod VARCHAR(50),
Fee1600 MONEY,
Fee1602 MONEY,
Fee1603 MONEY,
Fee1608 MONEY,
Fee1612 MONEY,
ADAAFunding MONEY,
ProgramBudget MONEY,
Jurisdiction INT,
VersionType VARCHAR(20),
VersionNum INT,
SubmitDate DATETIME
);

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GrantsInsert_sp]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (@GrantNumber AS VARCHAR(50), 
     @GrantName AS VARCHAR(100),
     @ProjectCode AS VARCHAR(50),
     @LOCID AS INT,
     @Comments AS VARCHAR(100),
     @Provider AS VARCHAR(100),
     @ISAT AS NCHAR(10),
     @TypeID AS INT,
     @Slots AS FLOAT,
     @Patients AS FLOAT,
     @FundingMethod AS VARCHAR(50),
     @Fee1600 AS MONEY,
     @Fee1602 AS MONEY,
     @Fee1603 AS MONEY,
     @Fee1608 AS MONEY,
     @Fee1612 AS MONEY,
     @ADAAFunding AS MONEY,
     @ProgramBudget AS MONEY,
     @Jurisdiction AS INT,
     @VersionType AS VARCHAR(20),
     @VersionNum AS INT)
AS BEGIN
 INSERT INTO dbo.Grants
    (GrantNumber,
     GrantName,
     ProjectCode,
     LOCID,
     Comments,
     Provider,
     ISAT,
     TypeID,
     Slots,
     Patients,
     FundingMethod,
     Fee1600,
     Fee1602,
     Fee1603,
     Fee1608,
     Fee1612,
     ADAAFunding,
     ProgramBudget,
     Jurisdiction,
     VersionType,
     VersionNum, 
     SubmitDate)
      -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT @GrantNumber, 
            @GrantName,
            @ProjectCode,
            @LOCID,
            @Comments,
            @Provider,
            @ISAT,
            @TypeID,
            @Slots,
            @Patients,
            @FundingMethod,
            @Fee1600,
            @Fee1602,
            @Fee1603,
            @Fee1608,
            @Fee1612,
            @ADAAFunding,
            @ProgramBudget,
            @Jurisdiction,
            @VersionType,
            @VersionNum,
            GETDATE();
END;

EXECUTE [GrantsInsert_sp] 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 1, 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 1, 1, 1, 'abc', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'abc', 1;

SELECT * FROM dbo.Grants;
```